# Unable to compare two numeric fields in SOSQL

Tags: soql

I am trying to compare two numeric fields in SOSQL on different Objects (> operator).
One of them is a formula field, the other a regular number.
I receive an unknown parser error.
I've even tried defining a second formula field for the regular number (so I can have both values on the same object, in case this was the issue.
I still receive the same error.
Does anybody have any ways to get around this?

Comment: SOQL or SOSL? Please edit your question to also include the query.

Comment: Thank you Kasper. This is SOSQL. Just noticed I have the wrong tag, sorry.
Here's the original query. It's the last test that fails -

SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(In_Form__Client__r.Id)

FROM In_Form__Timeline_Event__c

WHERE

In_Form__Start_date__c <= LAST_QUARTER

AND

(In_Form__End_date__c >= LAST_QUARTER OR In_Form__End_date__c=null)

AND

In_Form__Status__c = 'Open'

AND

In_Form__Project_Lookup__r.Name = 'Byron'

AND

Last_Quarter_Ending_Weeks_In_Project__c > In_Form__Project_Lookup__r.Maximum_stay__c

Comment: I'm not familiar with SOSQL, what is that part of?

Comment: Last_Quarter_Ending_Weeks_In_Project__c > In_Form__Project_Lookup__r.Maximum_stay__c

But, I think this has been answered by another comment. Thank you anyway Kasper.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE), *Fire Goat*! A few things: **1)** If you have an error, please copy/paste *exact* error text into your question. **2)** if you have code - including SOQL or SOSL, please include the pertinent code in your question. **3)** When you respond to comments asking for more info, like you did by adding your code at Kasper's request, do NOT answer in comments - add it your question. "Share Edit Follow Flag" are found at the bottom left of each Q & A - click *Edit*. **4)** If an answer works for you, click the check mark beside the answer to accept it.

Comment: Please take the [SFSE Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read more of the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help) to get to know the SFSE culture.

Comment: Thank you for the information Moonpie. I'll remember points 1)  to 3) and have ticked the answer. I'll take the tour also.

Comment: Great! Again, welcome. Those first few items are to help you get better and/or quicker help by providing specific information from the start and by ensuring that all of the information that someone with the knowledge to answer needs is easily found in the question, without having to sift through comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce does not allow direct field to field comparison in SOQL and SOSL queries: https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf.

> fieldExpression Syntax: fieldName comparisonOperator value

> The value must be a valid value, not other field names or calculations.

Here is a resolution for this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000331053&type=1. Create formula field on the object with comparison result and check it in the query.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it, thank you Mariia. I'll give this a go.
(what an incredible limitation though!)

Comment: You are welcome)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you Mariia. I would never have thought of this myself.

Comment: It's not a "workaround" - this is the way such comparisons must be implemented.

Comment: @PhilW FIne with that, let it be resolution as in help article)